# how to create session and fire query in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am novice in JPA 2.0.
Can someone tell me the steps how to create a new session and then execute query in JPA ?

Please do needful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have created a persistence.xml with a persistence unit tag. If you haven't then you need one here is the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPASamplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>org.cksoft.jpasample.entity.Person</class>
        <class>org.cksoft.jpasample.entity.Profile</class>
        <class>org.cksoft.jpasample.entity.Department</class>
        <class>org.cksoft.jpasample.entity.Skills</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyApp_DB" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" 
                /> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

After that you need to create EntityManagerFactory (if you are accessing it from main method)

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Here is how we can get a transaction and begin it and commit it.

```
em.getTransaction().begin(); 
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

After this you can keep using the EntityManager or close it

```
em.close();
```

Session is hibernate specific class which is almost as equal as EntityManager.
Correct me guys if I am wrong or something is missing thank you.

Comment: i have an entity manager object but my question is how to create a new session and then fire query and close the session

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a transaction to open and close it, Am I correct?

Comment: Is EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); create a new session or existing one ? I need to create new session.

Comment: It gives you a new entityManager and not a session. You can use the same entitymanager to carry out different transactions

Comment: thanks for the info but in my application there is a need to create a new session to audit the insert/update/delete transactions using AuditLogInterceptor.

Comment: what you can do is you can define a new persistence unit and can create a new entity manager and use it only for the purpose of Auditing.